# Complicated excel transpose

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula, transpose

Long story short I am stuck with a 700,000 record excel file that should only be around 10,000.  The records are stored in a very strange way.  See below.  If you think you can help, I would seriously appreciate it!!

We've spent hours upon hours trying to correctly transpose this data.

Trying to turn [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLhZW.png) into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb72m.png)

If you have any insight on how to fix this, please share.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Just a note - we added the "SKU" and "Description" column names after testing this.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am sorry for poorly wording the question.  I will make note of this for any further posts here.  Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shots aren't the best quality, so it's not very easy to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Nevertheless, for pivoting excel data sets, I always use Tableau's data reshaper plugin.  It's free and very easy to use.

**Link to Download**

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/addin-reshaping-data-excel

**Use**

A) Once you install the plugin,open excel and go to the Tableau tab.

B) Select the first VALUE in your table and select Unpivot.

C)  Thats it, you're done.

Comment: Okay sorry let me try to clarify.

Comment: @NYTB2016 better yet, can you post some data. Just the first 20 rows or so of the original and the expected output. Then we can actually test it before sending it back in the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Below is the small example, how I would implement it, assuming that I use named ranges for relevant columns: ItemName, Attribute and Value. The only issue - it might not work properly with 700K of records, but it could be split in few parts, e.g. 7 * 100K

[image: FindDistinctItems]

[image: MapAttributeValues]